# Why do my optimal number of clusters changes everytime I re-run the same code? Is this normal?

Tags: clustering

I have the following code:

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
from shapely.wkt import loads  # Make sure to import loads from shapely.wkt

# Convert WKT column to geometry
gdf_coefficients['geometry'] = gdf_coefficients['WKT'].apply(loads)
gdf_coefficients = gdf_coefficients.set_geometry('geometry')

# Iterate over each month's GeoDataFrame containing GWR coefficients
for (year, month), gdf_month in gdf_coefficients.groupby(['Year', 'Month']):
    # Extract GWR coefficients from the GeoDataFrame
    gwr_coefficients = gdf_month[['Intercept_coefficient', 'temperature_mean_coefficient', 'contact_mean_mean_coefficient',
                                   'policyIdx_max_coefficient', 'gdp_2019_coefficient', 'total_households_2021_coefficient',
                                   'population_density_coefficient', 'daytime_population_2021_coefficient',
                                   'elevation_mean_coefficient', 'NDVI_mean_coefficient', 'connectivity_index_coefficient']].values
    
    # Determine optimal number of clusters using Silhouette coefficient
    silhouette_scores = []
    for n_clusters in range(2, 11):
        spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors')
        labels = spectral.fit_predict(gwr_coefficients)
        silhouette_scores.append(silhouette_score(gwr_coefficients, labels))
    
    # Find the optimal number of clusters
    optimal_clusters = silhouette_scores.index(max(silhouette_scores)) + 2
    
    # Spectral Clustering with optimal number of clusters
    spectral = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=optimal_clusters, affinity='nearest_neighbors')
    gdf_month['spectral_cluster'] = spectral.fit_predict(gwr_coefficients)
    
    # Plot the clusters directly from gdf_month DataFrame
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    ax = gdf_month.plot(column='spectral_cluster', cmap='Wistia', legend=False, figsize=(12, 8))

    plt.title(f'Spectral Clustering Results for GWR - Year: {year}, Month: {month}')

    # Calculate cluster centers (average coefficients) for the current month
    cluster_centers = gdf_month.drop(['NUTS3', 'WKT', 'geometry'], axis=1).groupby('spectral_cluster').mean()

    # Calculate and plot cluster centers (centroids) for each spectral cluster
    for cluster, group in gdf_month.groupby('spectral_cluster'):
        cluster_union = group['geometry'].unary_union
        cluster_center = Point(cluster_union.centroid.x, cluster_union.centroid.y)
        
        # Plot cluster center
        plt.scatter(cluster_center.x, cluster_center.y, color=plt.cm.cool(cluster / (optimal_clusters - 1)), marker='o', s=50, alpha=1, label=f'Cluster {cluster} Center')

    # Create legend elements with correct colors
    legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=plt.cm.cool(cluster / (optimal_clusters - 1)), markersize=5, alpha=0.5, label=f'Cluster {cluster} Center') for cluster in cluster_centers.index]
    ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, title='Cluster Centers', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

    plt.show()

    # Print the optimal number of clusters
    print("Year:", year, "Month:", month, "Optimal number of clusters:", optimal_clusters)
```

And everytime that, for whatever reason, I re-run the code, the optimal number of clusters, based on Silhouette score and spectral clustering, changes.

I couldn't find any specific information if this is to be expected.

My original data has been preprocessed, normalized and standardized so I was wondering if this has something to do with noisy data or a random process of the algorithm.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Some clustering routines require seeds or start values. If those seeds change from iteration to iteration, so would the results.

Comment: I don't know Python at all, but I'm betting that somewhere in that code is a call to something that does some random sampling or generation and it's varying by trial.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) for `sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering`, specifically the section about `random_state` and the advice how to make the results deterministic across calls.

Comment: In addition to `random_state` you could increase the number of K-means iterations `n_init` to reduce run-to-run variability (fixing the seed won't remove sampling error).

Comment: Please tell us what you believe the code does.

Comment: @whuber ... the idea is to perfom spectral clustering with my GWR coefficients, and later to calculate the cluster centers (based on the average coefficients), and plot them in my map. Do you see anything strange/incoherent in the code? I would appreciate feedback.